# PrintStream write() method in Java

Tags: java, printstream

Directly from this Java [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write%28int%29):

> write
>
> public void write(int b)
>
> Writes the specified byte to this stream. If the byte is a newline and
>   automatic flushing is enabled then the flush method will be invoked.
>
> Note that the byte is written as given; to write a character that will
>   be translated according to the platform's default character encoding,
>   use the print(char) or println(char) methods.

I see it's specified `the byte is written as given;`
However if I try to `write(65)` I get the `A` I expected.

What should I write in `write()` in order to not match the same as it would be with `print()`?
Could you do any example?

Comment: Binary 65 (as a byte) is the ASCII character `A`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis read the question again, he expects the 'A'

Comment: `write(65)` will output `A` into the stream; `print(65)` will output `65` into the stream.

Comment: I think `print(65)` will take the Unicode char 65 (0x41), convert it using the default character encodeing to byte(s) and then write those bytes. If its UTF-8, it will be `A`. In fact, in lots of character encoding will it be `A`

Comment: @LeeMeador I would like to know the difference between "write the byte as it is" and using an encoding. "Byte as it is" I would expect something not encoded. However A is the result of an encoding

Comment: `print()` takes char or String types as parameters. These are Unicode. `write()` takes byte or byte[] types as parameters. These are just raw bits. Unicode can be decoded. Doing so ends up with one or more bytes. Those bytes can be encoded back to Unicode. `write(byte)` just transfers the bits to the file. `print(int)` considers the int to be a Unicode value, decodes it to a byte or bytes and transfers that byte or those bytes to the file.

Comment: `print(0x0391)` will convert that Unicode character (a greek capital alpha) to bytes. I don't know what those bytes are but would guess its two bytes in many encodings. Those two bytes, if I'm right, will go to the file.

Comment: so write(Alpha symbol) should write directly the bytes into the file right?

Answer (score 0):

Binary `01000001` (the `byte`) is the ASCII character `A` so you get that when you read as a `String`.

You would need to use [`FilterOutputStream.html#write(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D%29)

```
write("65".getBytes());
```

to get the same output.

Or whatever type you need

```
write(new Integer(65).toString().getBytes());
```

*What should I write in write() in order to not match the same as it would be with print()? Could you do any example?*

```
System.out.println(65); // writes 65 as a String, String.valueOf(65).getBytes()
System.out.write(65); // writes 65 as a byte
System.out.flush();
```

prints

```
65 // the String value '65'
A // the character value of binary 65
```

Read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) for the `print` methods. The one above accepts an `int` and

> Prints an integer. The string produced by **String.valueOf(int)** is
>   translated into bytes according to the platform's default character
>   encoding, and these bytes are written in **exactly the manner of the
>   write(int) method.**

In either case, bytes are written to the stream, but how they are displayed depends on the how your read them. `String` has constructors that accept a `charsetName` or `Charset` object. A [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) (as a concept and as a class) is

> A named mapping between sequences of sixteen-bit Unicode code units
>   and sequences of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

given

```
String s = "some string";
byte[] sData = s.getBytes();
```

`write(sData, 0, sData.length);`
and
`print(s);`

should be equivilent.

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
writer.print('Ä');
```

you might get varying results depending on your platform. It might be a single byte for a platform with Latin-1 as default encoding, or 2 bytes for a platform with UTF-8.